# Create a list of strings with intiger value from user input

Tags: python

First of all, I would like to apologize to anyone if there was a similar topic, but I've been looking for a solution on this for hours now and couldn't find anything. Perhaps I don't know exactly how to ask the question. I am quite new to python and programming in general.

So my issue is the following. I am currently working on my first little "project" that is not just following a guide or an example program. What I am trying to do is create a list string from user input bit the list must have an integer value this is what I am trying:

```
s1 = []
product = []
menu = 1
while menu > 0:
    print("1. Add employee.")
    print("2. Add a product.")
    print("3. Add a sale")
    print("4. quit")
    action = int(input("what would you like to do? Select a number: "))
    if action == 1:
        name = input("Employee name: ")
        s1.append(name)
    elif action == 2:
        temp = input("Select the name of the product: ")
        value = int(input("What is the price of the product: "))
        int_temp = temp
        product.append(int_temp)
        temp = value


    elif action == 4:
        menu = -1
```

I also tried the following:

```
temp = input("Select the name of the product? ")
product.append(temp)
value = int(input("What is the price of the product? "))
product[-1] = value
```

But then it just replaces the string of the product with the integer of the input I can't seem to make it a list of strings that can be referenced later in a calculation. I hope I was clear enough in my explanation of my problem and goal.

Comment: Sorry but i am not able to understand what is your end goal. Can you let us know what is the output you are expecting.

Comment: I guess I included some extra bits of the code that are not the main issue. My goal is in action 2 to ask the user for input of product and append it in a list. So far so good, but I also need to have a value attached to the list so I can use it in calculations later. And I also noticed I missed to create the list as it is mentioned in the answer.  let me try to explain it again if do:

Comment: ran out of space..
    temp = input(print("Select the name of the product? "))
    product.append(temp)
    value = int(input(print("What is the price of the product? ")))
    product[-1] = value
all it does is change the product name e.g. apples with the integer e.g. 3
what I need it to do is to be able to latter just say for example do something like daily sales = apples * 100 I hope this explains it better.

Comment: Also i edited your code to fix the syntax and semantic errors, please approve the edit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your comments i think you can use a dictionary instead of a list if you want to have a mapping of product name and product price. So the code would look like below

```
employees = []
products = {}
menu = 1


while menu > 0:
    print("1. Add employee.")
    print("2. Add a product.")
    print("3. Add a sale")
    print("4. quit")
    action = int(input("what would you like to do? Select a number: "))
    if action == 1:
        name = input("Employee name: ")
        employees.append(name)
    elif action == 2:
        product_name = input("Select the name of the product: ")
        product_price = int(input("What is the price of the product: "))
        products[product_name] = product_price
    elif action == 4:
        menu = -1
```

Then later in your code you can simply do like this.

```
sales = products['apples'] * 100
```

or

```
sales = products.get('apples', 0) * 100
```

Hope this helps !!

Comment: That is exactly what I wanted to do, thank you so much.

Comment: Glad to help, just fix your code in the question or simply approve my edit.

Answer (score 0):

Your code contains some errors, which I have mentioned below. Remove them and try again

Remove **print** from your input statements:

Like change this line:

```
name = input(print("Employee name: "))
```

to this:

```
name = input("Employee name: ")
```

Before this line of code:

```
product.append(int_temp)
```

make sure the product list is initiated like:

```
product = list()
```

And this line below:

```
product[-1] = value
```

will change the last value in the product list since -1 will refer to the last index, -2 will refer to second last and so on.

Comment: thanks for the syntax corrections and yeah I did miss to create the list. However product[-1] = value doesn't help the situation as it just replaces the last string in the integer(value) and I need it to be left as a string so I can reference it later. For example, if the user has entered apples and 3 for value and I would let's say I want to do daily sales of apples = apples * 100 the way it is now and with product[-1] = value doesn't help with it. Perhaps I didn't explained my end goal properly. still grateful for the quick answer!

Comment: @SimeonKostadinov brother, the way you describe your problem, it's difficult to understand. Please explain the problems in a simple way, just tell us what is your end **goal** and what is the **error** you are facing

Comment: By the way if you want to add values like these: *'apples': 3*
Then you can use a python dictionary; like you can write:
`product.append({'append': 3})`
it will append a dict in the product list